# Inequality using Hölder $x=\frac{y}{y-1}$ $y>1$

Tags: proof-writing, exponential-function, holder-inequality

> Prove that :
>   $$x^{x}+xy^{y-1}>(xy)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>   where $$x=\frac{y}{y-1}$$and
>   $\min(y,n)>1$.

I know that : Young inequality
$xy<\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}$

$q=\frac{p}{p-1}$

but how can I apply it here ?

Comment: Is $n$ unbounded in the interval $(1,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=1,$$ by Holder we obtain:
$$x^{x-1}+y^{y-1}=\frac{x^x}{x}+\frac{y^y}{y}\geq xy,$$
which gives
$$x^x+xy^{y-1}\geq x^2y$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$(x^2y)^n\geq xy,$$ which is true becase
$$(x^2y)^n\geq(xy)^n\geq xy.$$

Comment: Thank you  but I have $(xy)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ , then look to this ?$\min(x,y)(x^{x-1}+y^{y-1})>(xy)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?? Prove by same way ?

Comment: Can you complete !!

Comment: @Ellen Ellen I added something. See now.

Comment: Sir whene I need prove this $\min(x,y)(x^{x-1}+y^{y-1})>(xy)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$ $x,y>$  , I can use this method ! Whene $\min(x,y)=x$ and prove then $\min(x,y)=y$ and prove inequality ?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen Yes, of course! Since our inequality is symmetric, we can assume that $x\leq y$ and just  make the same things as in my solution.